# There are some errors for install yajl-ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When i run:

```
sudo gem install yajl-ruby
```

I see errors:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing yajl-ruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1/ext/yajl/gem_make.out
```

I have installed yum install ruby rubygems ruby-devel, but still have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
$ sudo gem install yajl-ruby
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. Still the same problem.

Comment: sudo gem install yajl-ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing yajl-ruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1/ext/yajl/gem_make.out

Comment: @user2378427 : try `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev ruby-dev`

Comment: try it
 sudo yum install libmysqlclient-devel ruby-devel
it works now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Telling people to modify things in /usr/bin/ manually (just to install a ruby gem) is borderline malicious.  I'm sad that this is the accepted answer.

Comment: myself client? no no you need libyajl-dev